# Proof: Clifford-Algebra representations are semisimple / completely reducible

Tags: representation-theory, clifford-algebras

There is a theorem:
**Every finite-dimensional Clifford-Algebra representation $V$ is semisimple / completely reducible**, which means that it's a direct sum of irreducible subrepresentations.

How this can be proven? Probably one has to construct to a given irreducible subrepresentation $U \subset V$ another subrepresentation $U' \subset V$, such that $U \oplus U' = V$. How?

Comment: Can you please cite some reference where you found this theorem?

Comment: @PrajwalSamal Possilby, in Lang XVII section 4. Clifford-algebra (over real number) is semisimple, and any module over semisimple ring is also semisimple.